# ProtectedMemory.Unprotect outputs garbage

Tags: c#, access-token, dpapi

I've got this code to store and recover an authorization token (which is alphanumeric):

```
public static void Store (string token)
{
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (token.PadRight (32));
    ProtectedMemory.Protect (buffer, MemoryProtectionScope.SameLogon);
    Settings.Default.UserToken = buffer.ToHexString ();
    Settings.Default.Save ();
}

public static string Retrieve ()
{
    byte[] buffer = Settings.Default.UserToken.FromHexString ();
    if (buffer.Length == 0)
        return String.Empty;
    ProtectedMemory.Unprotect (buffer, MemoryProtectionScope.SameLogon);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString (buffer).Trim ();
}
```

And it mostly works fine, although some times I get garbage out (many `FD` bytes, and some readable ones). I suspect this happens only when I reboot, but I've had some difficulties reproducing it.

Is this the intended behaviour? That is, does `MemoryProtectionScope.SameLogon` mean that the data will always be unreadable upon reboot? Am I doing something wrong?

The `FromHexString` and `ToHexString` methods do exactly what you would expect from them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `ProtectedMemory` will always fail after you reboot (or for the different `MemoryProtectionScope`s, restart the process etc.). It's only meant to work to protect memory, not data for storage.

You want to use `ProtectedData` instead:

```
ProtectedData.Protect(buffer, null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
```

Both of those are managed wrappers over the DPAPI (introduced with Windows 2000). There's a bunch of posts with more details on the .NET security blog - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/05/05/126825.aspx